# How do I get the value of a custom div variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this div in my reactJS project:

```
<div
              className="td-creator"
              id="Creator"
              tooltiptext="Melder"
              onMouseOver={setToolTip}
              onMouseOut={hideToolTip}
            >
```

I am trying to get the value of tooltiptext by using getelementbyid.
I can succesfully store the div element in a variable name target and when I print it in the console it shows me this:

[image: console message]

but when I try to use target.tooltiptext it returns undefined.
is there any way to acces the tooltiptext value in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because *tooltiptext* is not a property of the *HTMLDivElement*.

Try [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
const toolTipText = target.getAttribute("tooltiptext");
```

Comment: This Worked, thank you so much.
I had no idea this method exsisted.

Comment: @LokiTheShady, you are welocme:)

Comment: Be aware that any attributes that aren't part of the [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) should be prefixed as [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)attributes to prevent your HTML from being invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Most suitable way is to use [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes

Here is an example from https://developer.mozilla.org/

```
<article
  id="electric-cars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
   …
</article>

<script>
   const article = document.querySelector("#electric-cars");
   // The following would also work:
   // const article = document.getElementById("electric-cars")

   article.dataset.columns; // "3"
   article.dataset.indexNumber; // "12314"
   article.dataset.parent; // "cars"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAttribute` to get the value of that attribute:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#Creator').getAttribute('tooltiptext'));
```

```html
<div className="td-creator" id="Creator" tooltiptext="Melder" onMouseOver={setToolTip} onMouseOut={hideToolTip}></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer getAttribute is indeed the answer